# What is operator precedence of the *= operator in Java?

Tags: java, operator-keyword, operator-precedence

This comes from the section on Sets in Java Generics and Collections. The following example is given to illustrate how to compute a hashcode for String:

```
    int hash = 0;
    String str = "The red fox jumped over the fence";
    /** calculate String Hashcode **/
    for ( char ch: str.toCharArray()){
//      hash *= 31 + ch; this evaluates to 0 ????
        hash = hash * 31 + ch;
    }
    p("hash for " + str + " is " + hash);
```

hash for "The red fox jumped over the fence" is 1153233987386247098.
This appears to be correct. However, if I use the shorthand notation, *= , I get
0 for the answer.

```
    int hash = 0;
    String str = "The red fox jumped over the fence";
    /** calculate String Hashcode **/
    for ( char ch: str.toCharArray()){
        hash *= 31 + ch;
//      hash = hash * 31 + ch;
    }
    p("hash for " + str + " is " + hash);
```

hash for "The red fox jumped over the fence" is 0

So I am curious about how operator precedence is evaluated using the *= 
operator?

Comment: [The precedence of `*=` (and all other assignment operators) is the same as for `=`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html). That's why it does the addition before the multiplication and you get zero.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html

Answer (score 8):

```
hash *= 31 + ch;
```

is the same as

```
hash = hash * (31 + ch);
```

which explains the 0 result, since `hash` is initialized to 0 and remains 0 after each multiplication.

Before the `*=` operator is evaluated, its two operands (`hash` and `31+ch`) are evaluated. Only then they are multiplied and the result is stored in the `hash` variable.

In order to get the same output of

```
hash = hash * 31 + ch;
```

using `*=`, you'll have to break the operations:

```
hash *= 31;
hash += ch;
```

Comment: Or, since the most likely reason for using `*=` in the first place was to reduce typing, just *use* `hash = hash * 31 + ch` :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo That's certainly true :)

Comment: Your answer is very clear and logical. In fact, I assumed that was the case. However, I am curious is that actually correct on the part of the Implementers( java designers ) or was this a mistake on their part?

Comment: @GeorgeCurington I believe it would have been confusing if it behaved the way you expected, since you expected a single complex assignment operator to perform two assignments - first assign the result of the multiplication and then the result of the addition.

Comment: Ok maybe; This is my last comment regarding this. My logic flows as follows:

Comment: Ok maybe; This is my last comment regarding this. My logic flows as follows: If operators such as *= , +=  ... etc ... are simply syntatic sugar for their expanded counterparts, then they should behave semantically in the same way as the expanded counterpart. But they do not. so .. it is difficult to logically justify the  semantics.  In other words, a *= 8 +  3  should behave semantically the same as a = a * 8 + 3. The syntatic sugar changes the precedence; this feels incorrect to me.